# installation? whats there behind screens of linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, installation, libraries

I would focus on libraries though it can be a general application installation as well.

When we install a library (say C++), a novice user like me probably expects that when we "install" a library, all that source-code gets copied somewhere with few flags and path variables set so that we can directly use #include kind of statements in our own code and start using them.

But by inspection I can say that actually, the exact source-files are not copied but instead pre-compiled object-forms of the files are copied, except for the so called *.h header-files. (Simply because, I cannot find the sourcefiles all over the hard-disk except the headerfiles)

**My Questions:**

1. What is the behind scene method, when we "install" something.. what are all the typical locations that get affected by in a 'linux' environment. And the typical importance/use of each of those locations.
2. What is the difference between "installing" a library and installing a new application into the linux system via "sudo apt-get" or so.
3. Finally, If I have a custom set of source files which are useful as a library, and want to send them to another system, how would I "install" my own library there, in the same way as above.

Just to clarify, My primary interest is to know from your kind answers and literature-pointers, the bigger picture of a typical installation (an application/a library), to a level that I can crosscheck,learn and re-do if I want to.

Comment: In practice you usually install the "development" form of a library package as given by your distribution, for instance `apt-get install libgsl0-dev` on Debian. The distribution package manager take care of dependencies. And please read [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) and Levine's book on [linkers and loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/).

Comment: The question includes information about language libraries and their installation. when there are thousands of questions asked on C++ and l ibraries, I wonder why SO is not an appropriate place for this Q. <br/>  
The general software part of the question is merely for being a possible extension of this general procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. ***(Question was removed, question addressed difference between header and object files)*** This is more a question of general programming. A header file is just the declaration of classes/functions/etc, it does nothing. All a header file does is say "hey, I exist, this is what I look like." That is to say it's just a declaration of signatures used later in the actual code. The object code is just the compiled and assembled, but not linked code. [This diagram](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/images/GCC_CompilationProcess.png) does a good job of explaining the steps of what we generally call the "compilation" process, but would better be called the "compilation, assembling, and linking process." Briefly, linking is pulling in all necessary object files, including those needed from the system, to create a running executable which you can use.
2. ***(Now question 1)*** When you think about it, what is installation except the creation and modification of necessary files with the appropriate content? That's what installing is, just placing the new files in the appropriate place, and then modifying configuration files if necessary. As to what "locations" are typically affected, you usually see binaries placed in `/bin`, `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`; libraries are typically placed in `/lib` or `/usr/lib`. Of course this varies, depending. I think you'd find [this page on linux system directories](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/systemdirs.html) to be an educational read. Remember though, anything can be placed pretty much anywhere and still work appropriately as long as you tell other things where to find it, these directories are just used because they keep things organized and allow for assumptions about where items, such as binaries, will be located.
3. ***(Now question 2)*** The only difference is that [apt-get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) generally makes it easier by installing the item you need and keeping track of installed items, also it allows for easy removal of installed items. In terms of the actual installation, if you do it correctly manually then it should be the same. A package manager such as apt-get just makes life easier.
4. ***(Now question 3)*** If you want to do that you could create your own [package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_%28package_management_system%29) or if it's less involved, you could just create a script that moves the files to the appropriate locations on the system. However you want to do it, as long as you get the items where they need to be. If you want to create a package yourself, it'd be a great learning experience and there are plenty of tutorials are online. Just find out what package system your flavor of linux uses then look for a tutorial on how to create packages of that type.

So the really big picture, in my opinion, of the installation process is just compilation (if necessary), then the moving of necessary files to their appropriate places on the system, and the modification of existing files on the system if necessary: Put your crap there, let the system know it's there if you need to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response and sorry for the minor edits & removal of a question due to downvotes! 
Anyway, let me please wait for sometime till I see all responses if any.